# Writing contents of a table to csv in selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, csv, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am trying to automate (`selenium`) the process of writing the contents of my transcript to a csv file with python. So far I have automated the clicks to reach the page with the table. Currently I am only able to display the first row of the table, but the full content of that row appears in one cell.

This is currently the code I have pertinent to writing the contents of my transcript.

`id = 1`
[image]

This is how the `HTML table` code looks like:

[image]

For every table row, the id number increases by 1. For example, `VAR_STC_COURSE_NAME_1`, `VAR_STC_COURSE_NAME_2`, etc.
The number of rows changes as well depending on the number of courses taken.

I expect a csv file with rows and separate columns for every field. Currently I get the contents of one row in one cell.

Comment: Please do not post snapshot.Post your code in text format so that OP can provide you solution.

Answer (score 1):

`Import csv` first and then use `csv.writer` and `writerow([])`.

It will write data for each row.The code covers for csv part only.

```
import csv

with open('testfile.csv','w', newline='') as d:
  for row in main_table:
       csv.writer(d).writerow([course_name.text,grade.text,course_credits.txt,ceus.text,repeat_list.txt,term_list.txt])
```